# append Values in to one index and check if that index contains duplicated values

Tags: arrays, swift, swift4

I'm appending strings in to one index. I'm unable to check if that index contains the value that will be appended next.

Value of the string changes depending on the user input
How can I check if the elements array already contains "value1"?

Assuming that I have something like this:

```
var km: String = "1"
var meters: String = "1000"

var array: [String] = []
array.append(km + "Kilometers" + "=" + meters + "meters")

if array.contains(km) {
    //do something
}
```

I would like to check if the next value of km that user inputs is the same if it is inform the user that this has been already entered.

Comment: you already did it with contains

Comment: @Sh_Khan No, that use of `contains` will not find anything.

Comment: he may search the string content

Comment: @rmaddy yes that contains doesn't find anything. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @tom Your question is unclear. You append the literal string `"value1=value2"` to the array. Then you see if any object in the array is equal to the string `"value1"`. That of course isn't true. Please provide a clearer example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Sh_Khan the value of the string changes depending on the input

Comment: `contains` checks to see if any object in the array exactly matches the value passed to `contains`. If that is what you want then your code is fine. But if you actually want to see if any string in the array has some specific substring, then you need different code. But again, your question and needs are very unclear.

Comment: @ rmaddy I have edited the question

Comment: "I would like to check if the next value of km that user inputs is the same" Then no need to look in the array. Just hang on the value of km when the user inputs it, and check next time to see whether this is the same as the previous time. If you want to to know about all the km values the user has inputted, hang on to all of them.

Comment: @tom Keep in mind that your use of strings makes this difficult. What if you first add the string `"10Kilometers=10000meters"`. Then you want to see if `"1"` km has been added. Simply checking for the string `"1"` in your existing strings will likely give you a false positive.

Comment: I think he may get index of  Kilometers then check substring before it

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
  func searchArr(arr:[String],sear:String) -> Bool
  {

    for str in arr
    {
        if let range = str.range(of: "K") {

            let subStr = str[str.startIndex...range.lowerBound]

            if subStr.range(of:sear) != nil {

                return true
            }

        }

    }

    return false
}
```

Comment: Given the needs of the updated question, this can give false positives. Image the array contains `"10 kilometer..."` and now the OP wants to check to see if `"1"` km has been added.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

`elements.reduce(false) {$0 || $1.contains("value1")}`

Because you're REDUCING an array into a bool

Comment: This is really inefficient. You will needlessly scan the entire array even if the first string matches.

Comment: That's fair, I just liked the Swift-yness of using a high level function like this.